# How to put a RegExp inside a JavaScript object literal aka object initializer with a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, regex, filter, sapui5

I wish for filtering aim to put a RegExp inside a javascript template on a javascript variable, here the filter (with no RegExp) :

```
sValue = oEvent.target.value,
aVisibleItems1 = this.filterItems({
                        property: "text",
                        value: sValue
                    });
```

this correspond to a combo box (overrided for including search), this filter works find but not for contain, only for exact match with the beginning of the line, then I wanted to use RegEx then i tried :

```
sValue = oEvent.target.value,
aVisibleItems1 = this.filterItems({
                        property: "text",
                        value: /sValue/i
                    });
```

it didn't work (I suppose considering sValue as 'sValue') then i tried :

```
sValue = oEvent.target.value,
aVisibleItems1 = this.filterItems({
                        property: "text",
                        value: new RegExp(sValue, "i")
                    });
```

it didn't work either (I suppose because format ?).
So how could I do something similar ?
Thank you in advance :)

PS: in anoter cateogy for the the same aim I also tried :

```
sValue = oEvent.target.value,
oItem=this.getItems()
aVisibleItems1 = this.setFilterFunction(function(sValue, oItem) {
                return this.oItem.getText().match(new RegExp(sValue, "i"))
            });
```

and

```
sValue = oEvent.target.value,
aVisibleItems1 = this.setFilterFunction(searchTextContain(this.getItems(), sValue));
function searchTextContain(items, sValueToSearch) {
            var sResearch = [];
            for (var item of items) {
                if (item.getText().match(new RegExp(sValueToSearch, "i")) != null) {
                    sResearch.push(item);
                }
            }
            return sResearch;
        }
```

it also didn't work, i would prefer a solution looking like the 2 first try with RegExp if there is one, Because I have to use this.filterItems for filter in the UI the listItem, but if you have other solution I will also be glad, the aim is to have filtered value

Comment: `it didn't work ` what's the error?

Comment: @AZ_ for the 2 last function error on UI5 core file, for the 2 first no error just not working (the array aVisibleItems1 stay empty and it shouldn't because it is not with the same entry without RegExp for example with entry p (lenght 160 without RegExp empty with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution, as my problem was with filterItems I overwrite this function,
I created a control ComboBoxContain which override ComboBox filterItems as follow :

```
ComboBox.prototype.filterItems = function(mOptions, aItems) {
            var sProperty = mOptions.property,
                sValue = mOptions.value,
                bEmptyValue = sValue === "",
                bMatch = false,
                sMutator = "get" + sProperty.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + sProperty.slice(1),
                aFilteredItems = [],
                oItem = null;

            aItems = aItems || this.getItems();
            if (!bEmptyValue) {
                for (var i = 0; i < aItems.length; i++) {

                    oItem = aItems[i];

                    // the item match with the value
                    bMatch = (oItem[sMutator]().match(new RegExp(sValue, "i")) !== null);

                    if (bMatch) {
                        aFilteredItems.push(oItem);
                    }

                    this._setItemVisibility(oItem, bMatch);
                }
            }
            return aFilteredItems;
        };
```